# Netlogo missing inconsistent results when iterating through a list of ~ 6K lists

Tags: list, foreach, netlogo

I'm setting up patches from values read from a file. The values are in a list of lists:

`[[10001 53 1 2 160 4 4 4 1] [10004 69 1 2 143 4 4 4 2] [10005 70 2 2 135 3 3 4 2] [10006 51 2 2 132 4 4 3 3] ... ]`

Each "internal" list has the values for the properties of a patch.
The value in position 2 (I'm counting from 0 for the first value) represents gender:
 `1`=male, `2`=female.

My procedure:

```
 to setup-patches-as-agents [ patches-data ]
    set male-count 0
    set female-count 0
    set total-rows 0
    foreach patches-data [
       [ one-row ] ->  
       ask patches with [ pxcor = random-pxcor and pycor = random-pycor]  
       [ set total-rows total-rows + 1
      ;; add values to patch properties
      ;; ****  id  ****
      set p-midus_id item 0 one-row
      ;; **** age *****
      set p-age item 1 one-row
      ;; gender 1= MALE; 2= FEMALE; 7= DON'T KNOW; 8= REFUSE            
      set p-gender item 2 one-row   
      if item 2 one-row =  1 ;; male
        [ set pcolor blue
          set male-count male-count + 1 ]  ;; male
      if item 2 one-row =  2 ;; female
        [ set pcolor orange
          set female-count female-count + 1 ] ;; female
      ;; **** lose10lb ****
      set p-lose10lb item 3 one-row
      ;; **** weightYrAgo ****
      set p-weightYrAgo item 4 one-row
     ;; **** limitLiftCarryGroceries ****
      set p-limitLiftCarryGroceries item 5 one-row
      ;; **** limitClimbingStairs ****
      set p-limitClimbingStairs item 6 one-row
      ;; **** limitWalkingSeveralBlocks ****
      set p-limitWalkingSeveralBlocks item 7 one-row
      ;; **** limitWalkingSeveralBlocks ****
      set p-limitWalkingSeveralBlocks item 8 one-row
    ]   
  ]
  type "male-count: "
  print male-count
  type "female-count: "
  print female-count
  type "total-count: "
  print total-rows
end
```

The total number of rows read is: 6325  (output after reading the file, which matches the number of rows in the file
 Total number of Males should be: 3004, and for females: 3321. The count I get with those variables changes, including the total number of "rows"

Any idea why??

Answer (score 2):

Glad you figured out a workaround! Just to give my two cents, I think your solution points to the likely issue with your first code- your

`ask patches with [ pxcor = random-pxcor and pycor = random-pycor]`

did not remove patches with assigned values from the pool of patches- that is to say you could have a patch be chosen multiple times, and so its initial values would be overwritten every time it was chosen. Since in your `turtles` solution you create a new turtle for each row, there is no overwriting happening.

If you need it to be patches instead of turtles, you can change your with statement to something that only selects patches that have not had values assigned yet. For example (assuming your setup does not previously set p-gender), you could take advantage of the fact that all declared variables are by default set to 0 until they are changed in code and change your original code to something like

```
...
foreach patches-data [
  [ one-row ] -> 
  ask one-of patches with [ p-gender = 0 ] [ 
...
```

In the same pass you can just use `one-of` rather than manually choosing a random `pxcor` and `pycor`- it's simpler I think.

Additionally, and this is obviously up to you, instead of manually incrementing your counter for `male` and `female`, you might want to just set up a `to-report` procedure that monitors those for you. For example, if you have this in your code:

```
to-report male-turtle-count
  report count turtles with [ gender = 1 ]
end
```

and then you `print male-count` (or use a monitor on the interface), it will show you the number of turtles that currently have a gender of 1. This dynamically updates so you don't have to keep track of a counter.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to turtles and setup all properties, including initial coordinates and now I'm getting the right counts. I suspect that the condition for the coordinates to select a patch might be an issue, but I'm not sure. Anyway, here's my solution:

```
to setup-turtles [ turtles-data ]
  foreach turtles-data [
    [ one-row ] -> 
    crt 1 [
      set shape "square"
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      set size 2
      ;;(item 0 one-row) and ycor = (item 1 one-row) ] [
      ;; ****  id  ****
      set midus_id item 0 one-row
      ;; **** age *****
      set age item 1 one-row
      ;; gender 1= MALE; 2= FEMALE; 7= DON'T KNOW; 8= REFUSE            
      set gender item 2 one-row 
      if item 2 one-row =  1 ;; male
        [ set color blue ]  ;; male
      if item 2 one-row =  2 ;; female
        [ set color orange ] ;; female
      ;; **** lose10lb ****
      set lose10lb item 3 one-row
      ;; **** weightYrAgo ****
      set weightYrAgo item 4 one-row
     ;; **** limitLiftCarryGroceries ****
      set limitLiftCarryGroceries item 5 one-row
      ;; **** limitClimbingStairs ****
      set limitClimbingStairs item 6 one-row
      ;; **** limitWalkingSeveralBlocks ****
      set limitWalkingSeveralBlocks item 7 one-row
      ;; **** physicalFitnessCompared5YrAgo ****
      set physicalFitnessCompared5YrAgo item 8 one-row
    ]  
  ]
end
```